# Не понимаю сути ошибки при отладке Android приложения, в Visual Studio Code в среде разработки Flutter

Tags: android, visual-studio-code, flutter, отладка, flutter-ui

При отладке приложения выходит ошибка.

```
Reload already in progress, ignoring request: Error: 'UnreadIndicator' is imported from both 'package:paradox_chat/widgets/unread_Indicator.dart' and 'package:paradox_chat/widgets/unread_indicator.dart'.
lib/pages/messanges_page.dart:153
                      child: UnreadIndicator(
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```
import 'package:faker/faker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:jiffy/jiffy.dart';
import 'package:paradox_chat/helpers.dart';
import 'package:paradox_chat/models/models.dart';
import 'package:paradox_chat/screens/screens.dart';
import 'package:paradox_chat/theme.dart';
import 'package:paradox_chat/widgets/unread_Indicator.dart';

import 'package:paradox_chat/widgets/widgets.dart';
import 'package:stream_chat_flutter_core/stream_chat_flutter_core.dart';
import 'package:paradox_chat/app.dart';

class _MessageTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const _MessageTile({
    Key? key,
    required this.channel,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Channel channel;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(ChatScreen.routeWithChannel(channel));
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 100,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
            bottom: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.grey,
              width: 0.2,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Avatar.medium(
                    url:
                        Helpers.getChannelImage(channel, context.currentUser!)),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        Helpers.getChannelName(channel, context.currentUser!),
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          letterSpacing: 0.2,
                          wordSpacing: 1.5,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                      child: _buildLastMessage(),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment:
                      CrossAxisAlignment.end, //положение уведомления сообщения
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(
                      //отступ уведомления от вверха
                      height: 4,
                    ),
                    _buildLastMessageAt(),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 8,
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: UnreadIndicator(
                        channel: channel,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что в двух файлах
`package:paradox_chat/widgets/unread_indicator.dart` и `package:paradox_chat/widgets/unread_Indicator.dart` содержатся один и тот же класс. Попробуйте удалить один из этих файлов или импортировать с ключевым словом.

```
 import "package:paradox_chat/widgets/unread_indicator.dart" as indicator;
```

А потом используйте как

```
 indicator.UnreadIndicator
```